# React Choosing the Type at Runtime

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to load a react component during run time, but I am getting this error.
[image]

Please find the code that i have written for my usecase:
-> index.js

```
import { useEffect,useState } from "react";
import SectionFactory from "./section3/SectionFactory";

export default function TestHome3(){
    const [sectionType,setSectionType]  = useState();


    const sectionTypeChanged=(e)=>{
        const {name,value} = e.currentTarget;
        setSectionType(value);
    }

    return(
        <>
            
            <select name="sectiontype" id="sectiontype" className="mt-1 px-3 py-2 bg-white border shadow-sm border-slate-300 placeholder-slate-400 focus:outline-none focus:border-sky-500 focus:ring-sky-500 block w-full rounded-md sm:text-sm focus:ring-1"
            onChange={(e)=>{
                sectionTypeChanged(e);
            }}
            >
                <option value="freetext">Free Text</option>
                <option value="Pills">Pills</option>
                <option value="timebound">Time Bound</option>
                <option value="urllinks">URL Links</option>
            </select>

            
            <SectionFactory type={sectionType}/>  
        
          
        </>
    )
}
```

->SectionFactory.js

```
import Pills from "./PillFact";
const sectioncomp = {
    Pills
};
export default function SectionFactory(props){
   
    const Section = sectioncomp[props.type];
    return <Section/>

}
```

->PillFact.js

```
export default function PillFact(props){
   
    return(
        <>
         welcome to pills
        </>
    )
}
```

I have read the documentation from react here https://legacy.reactjs.org/docs/jsx-in-depth.html and also followed some blogs and existing stackoverflow issues. But i am not able to understand what am i missing here.

Please help me identify the issue and get this resolved.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: `sectionType` starts as undefined because of `const [sectionType,setSectionType]  = useState();`. Then you try creating `<SectionFactory type={sectionType}/> ` which leads to `const Section = sectioncomp[undefined]` and then `<Section/>` will result in an error.

Comment: In SectionFactory.js , `const Section = sectioncomp[props.type];`  unable to read type. `type` is `undefined`.

Comment: It still won't work, because you can't just pass a random string and expect react to find out which component you meant

Answer (score 0):

Just ensure to set an initial value for `sectionType` to avoid issues when rendering.

```
const [sectionType, setSectionType] = useState("freetext"); // Set an initial value
```

This way, when the component renders initially, it will pass the `"freetext"` value to the `SectionFactory`, and you won't encounter issues due to an initial `undefined` value.